# Beginner rails: submit_tag issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay, so basically I am doing a web application where I want the user to input a given value for a constant named @radius which I will later use.

Say I have the following code in a view named "business/index.html.erb"

```
<%= form_tag root_path do %>
   <%= number_field_tag :radius %>
   <%= submit_tag "add" %>
<% end %>
```

And then I have the following code in my business_controller under the index action:

```
@radius= params[:radius] || @radius || 1
```

My routes file:

```
root :to => 'business#index'
post "business/index"
```

Basically, the view is looking nice, yet when I actually change the radius and submit it, it still defaults to one as if params[:radius] is nil. Any ideas of what I am missing? I'm sure it is quite elementary.

EDIT:

Here is part of the logfile which I believe is what I was asked for

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 02:00:31 -0430
Processing by BusinessController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CaD40O9gAedbeDepeDHtrMNNWzD/uBznHZ30ZGy+c6Q=", "radius"=>"2", "commit"=>"add"}
  [1m[35mBusiness Load (18.0ms)[0m  SELECT businesses.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((10.5083644 - businesses.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(10.5083644 * PI() / 180) * COS(businesses.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-66.83536699999999 - businesses.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(businesses.longitude - -66.83536699999999), RADIANS(businesses.latitude - 10.5083644))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing, ( businesses.reviews_count / (nullif(businesses.reviews_count + MAX(businesses.reviews_count) OVER(),0)) ) * businesses.rating + (MAX(businesses.reviews_count) OVER() / (nullif(businesses.reviews_count+MAX(businesses.reviews_count) OVER(),0))) * AVG(businesses.rating) OVER() as ranking FROM "businesses" WHERE (businesses.latitude BETWEEN 10.490377967881624 AND 10.526350832118375 AND businesses.longitude BETWEEN -66.85366024099285 AND -66.81707375900713 AND 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((10.5083644 - businesses.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(10.5083644 * PI() / 180) * COS(businesses.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-66.83536699999999 - businesses.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) <= '2') GROUP BY businesses.id ORDER BY distance ASC, ranking DESC
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

Comment: I expected the @radius constant to change depending on what I input in the number_field_tag instead of still defaulting to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the `@radius` variable and how it works.  This is an instance variable of the controller, so it will be reset to `nil` between every request.  If you want to persist the value of radius between requests you will need to do it in a database, or in the users cookie.

A session cookie implementation might look like this:

```
session[:radius] = params[:radius] || session[:radius] || 1
```

Then, for your view and form you will need reference the session directly, or define `@radius = session[:radius]` in your controller action.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I am new to session implementation, is there anything I need to add in my routes file or somewhere else? I tried the code as you put it and it still did not work.

Comment: sessions are built into rails to track a users session, they are not related to routes.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session